# svg circle too small for mouseevent

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I am working on a D3 Graph. My graph has circles with no fill color which look like this:

```
var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
.data(x.ticks(6))
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("r", function (d) { return radius(d); })
.style("fill", "none")
.style("stroke", "black")
.style("stroke-dasharray", "3,3")
.style("stroke-width", "1px")
```

I have added a mouse event to that circle so that whenever someone hovers over it, the circle would get larger width:

```
.on('mouseenter', function (a, i) {
  d3.select(this)
  .style("stroke-dasharray", "0")
  .style("stroke-width", "3px")
})
```

However, the width of the circle is too small to be easily touchable without extra effort. What would be a good and efficient solution to make the hit slop bigger so that the mouseevent would trigger with ease?

Comment: draw another hidden circle on top and hit test that instead.

Comment: will you please add jsfiddle or stackblitz so we would have more sense of your problem

Answer (score 0):

The best option is control the minimum circle radius(the radius where it is easily touchable).That means, if a circle is not easily touchable when radius < 5px then keep minimum radius as 5px.